# Faces Flow not navigating beyond two pages

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, flow-scope

I have created a faces flow which was working perfectly until I added a third page to the flow. For some reason I can only navigate to the third page in the flow when I refresh the web page on the 2nd flow. Otherwise when I click next nothing happens.

Comment: Could you post some code?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have solved part of the problem. I had made an ajax call on the 2nd view and the backing bean for my flow is @RequestCoped. Therefore, the backing bean would die after the ajax call  since a request scoped bean lives as long as a single HTTP request-response cycle.